# How to implement a recursive search in Laravel 4?

Tags: recursion, laravel

I am trying to create a posts <-> comments relationship tables and display the results.

I think I can create all the relationships properly, but I am missing the recursive function in the View to display them correctly. Here is my code:

my posts table is:

```
   id | subject | content |
```

my comments table is:

```
id | content | post_id | parent_id
```

As you can see, I relate the comments table with the posts ones with the "post_id", and relate the comments table to itself with de "parent_id" for those comments that are children of others.

Now, these are my models. For the Post I have:

```
<?php
class Post extends Eloquent{
    public function comments(){//Me captura el primer bloque de replies
        return $this->hasMany('Comment')->where('parent_id',0);
    }
}
?>
```

and my Comment Model is:

```
<?php
class Comment extends Eloquent{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Post');
    }
    public function nestedComment(){
        return $this->hasMany('Comment','parent_id');   
    }
}
?>
```

I think those relationships should be enough to create the view (which I have no idea how to build using a recursive function), so far I have this:

```
@if($posts)
    @foreach($posts as $post)                       {{-- for posts --}}
        <strong>{{$post->subject}}</strong><br />
        @foreach($post->comments as $comment)       {{-- for 1st reply --}}
            <p id="reply1">{{$comment->content}}</p>
            @if($comment->nestedComment->count() >0)  {{-- for reply reply --}}
                @foreach($comment->nestedComment as $nestedComment)
                    <p id="reply2">{{$nestedComment->content}}</p>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@else
@endif
```

Of course with this type of view I can just get to show the first reply of a reply, but cannot go any deeper...

Any idea about how I can build this View and get to display as deep as the replies are?

Thanks in advanced from Costa Rica.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am going to try:

```
function display_comment($comment, $indent) {

  echo $indent, $comment, PHP_EOL;

  if ( $comment->nestedComment )
    display_comment($comment->nestedComment, $indent + INDENT);

}
```

I haven't been able to implement it though